# Convert rows into columns without using PIVOT or Cased Aggregate Functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table named customers in my database which has retailers(customers)
and distributors seperated by typeid (Eg: typeid=1 customers and typeid=2 distributors)

Now there is mapping table in which there are mappings of customers and distributors.
Note that a Retailer or Customer will at most have only two distributors.

Below is the Mapping table.

```
| Customer    | Distributor  |
    ----------------------------
    |   Customer1 | Distributor1 | 
    |   Customer1 | Distributor2 |  
    |   Customer2 | Distributor1 |  
    |   Customer2 | Distributor3 |  
    |   Customer3 | Distributor2 |
```

I want to represent this table as follows

```
| Customer    | Partner1     | Partner 2     |
---------------------------------------------------
| Customer1   | Distributor1 | Distributor2  |
| Customer2   | Distributor1 | Distributor3  |
| Customer3   | Distributor2 | Null          |
```

the concept of Pivot  struck me but there is no column to perform aggregate function on for pivot to be applied.

Any simple ways to attain the desired result?

PS: I have already thought of getting two different sets from two temp tables and then join them, but that looks to be tedious.Help me if some one could point me towards the result with a simpler solution .

Comment: Are you using mysql or sql server? They are not the same thing.

Comment: I removed the extraneous database tags.  Please tag the question with the database you are actually using.

Comment: @JohnConde I am using sql server 2012

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate the column need for pivoting by using `row_number()`:

```
select customer,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then distributor end) as distributor1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then distributor end) as distributor2
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by customer order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by customer;
```

Comment: That worked for me though I have not understood what it means. Would be great if you can explain what exactly is happening in that query of yours? What is the use of partition by?